# Regex with multiple conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I'm trying to have the following rules for NSString validation using regular expression:

- 8 characters minimum length
- at least 1 digit
- at least 1 uppercase
- at least 1 lowercase

I'm only able to do the following to get the first rule like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$
```

Which if i understand correctly check for minimum 8 characters length with lower/uppercase and digit

Thank you

Comment: Your regex checks only for the 8 characters minimum, and rejects all characters except `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. This would match a string of eight digits or eight lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookahead for each assertion:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])^.{8,}$
```